# Asp.net masterpage is not displaying in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, master-pages

I built an internal site for my company with asp.net.  I copied the site to the server and tested every page in both firefox and ie and everything looked fine, but i noticed that i forgot to add titles to a couple pages.  After adding the titles and copying the updated files to the server, my master page is no longer showing when viewed in ie.  All the content is still displayed, but nothing from my master page.  Firefox is displaying everything normally.  I have tried recopying all the files and restarting the app pool.  When i use ie to browse the site from the server everything works fine.  Everything works fine when i preview the site locally with vwd2010.  I have tried viewing the site from 3 different machines with ie and they all are showing the same thing.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?

MasterPage

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs"     Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>
                        register support
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="howto.aspx" Text="Common Problems"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="search.aspx" Text="Search"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/incidents.aspx" Text="Incidents" />
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server" />
            </div>      

        </div>
        <div class="bottomlinks">
            <a href="Admin/managebroadcasts.aspx">[administrators]</a>    
        </div>  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Content Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="place1" runat="server" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="place2" runat="server" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Show your Code on how your master page is setup ..

Comment: Maybe Firefox show you cached version or your site is not IE compatible. You need to put a lot of effort to make it work in IE :(

Answer (score 0):

I am working with master pages and I would like to see what the top of your .aspx web page looks like.. for example it should look something like this

```
<%@ Page Title="Student Registration" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="StudentInfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="MRC_IDSWeb.Pages.StudentInfo" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Set the Page Title in the page Header Separately.. not in the html like you would in a .aspx page that does not utilize MasterPages hope this makes sense to you

Comment: I added the top.  I actually took the title back to the way it was to see if it fixed the problem, but it had no effect

Comment: This should work.. is there anywhere else in your code where you are trying to assign the Title.. can you show the Code Behind of the page that is not working / html markup as well as what your full master page code looks like.. it's hard to determine without seeing what you actually have in regards of code

Comment: Its actually all the pages on the site and there are 2 master pages.  I navigated to the site and did a view source.  All the master page stuff is there, but it isn't displayed.  I copied the source into a html file, and that file opens fine with ie.

Comment: I can't think of anything else without seeing a small portion of code.. so I am not sure how else to guide you..

Comment: Can you paste that in your original question..?

Comment: How come you are not adding a value to the <%@ Page Title="" Put a value for the Title ...it's not going to populate itself automatically unless you assign a value to it

Comment: That was the change I made.  I changed it back to the way i had it.

Comment: Now I am confused you should assign a value to the page even if it's hard coded or holding the value of the Page title in a Session variable.. does the code show up properly when you debug your code..?

Comment: I ended up just remaking all of the master pages and then it worked so clearly i changed something and couldnt find it.  Thanks for all of your help